# How to wait multiple threads while a common task is being carried out?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, thread-synchronization

I have multiple threads executing API calls parallelly. Whenever the jwt token expires i want all my threads to wait until the refresh token API is called and returns with valid updated jwt token. I have a singleton class which has a refresh token method which will make the call and update the token. How can I make sure that all my other threads will wait until token fetch is complete?

```
public class JWTTokenManager
    {
        private static JWTTokenManager _tokenManager;
        private string _token;
        private bool _refreshingToken;

        public static JWTTokenManager GetManager()
        {
            if (_tokenManager == null)
                _tokenManager = new JWTTokenManager();
            return _tokenManager;
        }

        public void UpdateToken(string token)
        {
            _token = token;
        }

        public string GetToken()
        {
            return _token;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ValidateRefreshTocken()
        {
            UserInfo userdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(GetUserInfo(_token), new Helper.DefaultJsonSetting());
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userdata.Exp) && TokenExpired(long.Parse(userdata.Exp)))
            {
                _refreshingToken = true;
                JWTToken jwtToken = Database.DBService.GetDB().FetchJWTToken();
                RefreshToken requestRefresh = new RefreshToken
                {
                    ExpiredTocken = jwtToken.Token,
                    RefreshTocken = jwtToken.RefreshToken
                };
                HttpClient httpClient = CloudService.GetCloudService().GetHttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"account/v1/tokenRefresh", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestRefresh), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                bool responseStatus = await ParseTokenResponseAsync(response);
                _refreshingToken = false;
                return responseStatus;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private string GetUserInfo(string key)
        {
            string[] base64Url = key.Split('.');
            if (base64Url.Length > 1)
            {
                string userinfo = base64Url[1];
                userinfo = userinfo.Replace(" ", "+");
                int mod4 = userinfo.Length % 4;
                if (mod4 > 0)
                {
                    userinfo += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
                }
                var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(userinfo);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        public bool TokenExpired(long unixTimeStamp)
        {
            DateTime tokenExpiryDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            tokenExpiryDateTime = tokenExpiryDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            return DateTime.Compare(tokenExpiryDateTime, currentDateTime) <= 0;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ParseTokenResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
        {
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
            {
                string responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject responsedataObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseString);
                string token = responsedataObject["data"]["token"].ToString();
                string refreshToken = responsedataObject["data"]["refreshToken"].ToString();
                _token = token;
                JWTToken updatedToken = new JWTToken()
                {
                    Token = _token,
                    RefreshToken = refreshToken
                };
                Database.DBService.GetDB().InsertOrUpdateJWTToken(updatedToken);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
public class CloudService
{
    private const int TIME_OUT = 50;
    private const int HTTP_GET = 0;
    private const int HTTP_PUT = 1;
    private const int HTTP_POST = 2;
    private const int HTTP_DELETE = 3;

    private static CloudService _serviceInstance;

    public static CloudService GetCloudService()
    {
        if (_serviceInstance == null)
            _serviceInstance = new CloudService();
        return _serviceInstance;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteHttpTask(int taskType, string url, StringContent content = null)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClient();
        switch (taskType)
        {
            case HTTP_GET:
                return await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            case HTTP_PUT:
                return await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
            case HTTP_POST:
                return await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            case HTTP_DELETE:
                return await httpClient.DeleteAsync(url);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<Response> HTTPTask(string url, int taskType, StringContent content = null, bool login = false)
    {
                bool refreshTocken = await JWTTokenManager.GetManager().ValidateRefreshTocken();

        Response httpResponse = new Response();
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await ExecuteHttpTask(taskType, url, content);

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                httpResponse.status = "error";
            else
                httpResponse.status = "data";
            httpResponse.data = ParseResponseData(httpResponse.status, responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            httpResponse = GenericErrorResponse(e.Message);
        }
        return httpResponse;
    }

    public async Task<Response> GetSectionAsync(string id)
    {
        string url = $"catalog/v2/homepageSections/{id}?order-by=name,asc";
        return await HTTPTask(url, Constants.HTTP_GET);
    }

    public async Task<Response> GetProductAsync(string id)
    {
        string url = $"catalog/v2/products/{id}";
        return await HTTPTask(url, Constants.HTTP_GET);
    }

    public async Task<Response> GetCourseDetailsAsync(string id)
    {
        string url = $"catalog/v2/products/{id}/courseDetails";
        return await HTTPTask(url, Constants.HTTP_GET);
    }

}
```

Different threads will call methods in ClouService which in turn calls different APIs parallelly and all these go through the HTTPTask method, where the token is validated and if not valid, API is called to get the updated token. How can I make all the APIs(the threads) to wait from the moment when token is invalid and until the API returns valid token?

Based on the comments I have updated both the classes. Please have a look.

```
public sealed class JWTTokenManager
    {
        private static readonly JWTTokenManager _tokenManager = new JWTTokenManager();
        private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        private string _token;
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static JWTTokenManager()
        {
        }
        private JWTTokenManager()
        {
        }

        public static JWTTokenManager GetManager()
        {
            return _tokenManager;
        }

        public void UpdateToken(string token)
        {
            _token = token;
        }

        public string GetToken()
        {
            return _token;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ValidateRefreshTocken(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            bool validToken;
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                UserInfo userdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(GetUserInfo(_token), new DefaultJsonSetting());
                if (forceRefresh || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userdata.Exp) && TokenExpired(long.Parse(userdata.Exp)))
                {
                    validToken = await RefreshToken();
                }
                else
                {
                    validToken = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                validToken = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
            return validToken;
        }

        private async Task<bool> RefreshToken()
        {
            JWTToken jwtToken = Database.DBService.GetDB().FetchJWTToken();
            RefreshToken requestRefresh = new RefreshToken
            {
                ExpiredTocken = jwtToken.Token,
                RefreshTocken = jwtToken.RefreshToken
            };
            HttpClient httpClient = CloudService.GetCloudService().GetHttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"account/v1/tokenRefresh", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestRefresh), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            bool status = await ParseTokenResponseAsync(response);
            return status;
        }

        private string GetUserInfo(string key)
        {
            string[] base64Url = key.Split('.');
            if (base64Url.Length > 1)
            {
                string userinfo = base64Url[1];
                userinfo = userinfo.Replace(" ", "+");
                int mod4 = userinfo.Length % 4;
                if (mod4 > 0)
                {
                    userinfo += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
                }
                var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(userinfo);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        public bool TokenExpired(long unixTimeStamp)
        {
            DateTime tokenExpiryDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            tokenExpiryDateTime = tokenExpiryDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            return DateTime.Compare(tokenExpiryDateTime, currentDateTime) <= 0;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ParseTokenResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
        {
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
            {
                string responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject responsedataObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseString);
                string token = responsedataObject["data"]["token"].ToString();
                string refreshToken = responsedataObject["data"]["refreshToken"].ToString();
                _token = token;
                JWTToken updatedToken = new JWTToken()
                {
                    Token = _token,
                    RefreshToken = refreshToken
                };
                Database.DBService.GetDB().InsertOrUpdateJWTToken(updatedToken);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

public sealed class CloudService
    {
        private const int TIME_OUT = 50;
        private const int HTTP_GET = 0;
        private const int HTTP_PUT = 1;
        private const int HTTP_POST = 2;
        private const int HTTP_DELETE = 3;

        private static readonly CloudService _serviceInstance = new CloudService();
        static CloudService()
        {
        }
        private CloudService()
        {
        }

        public static CloudService GetCloudService()
        {
            return _serviceInstance;
        }

        public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TIME_OUT),
                BaseAddress = new Uri($"{AppConst.ServerBaseURL}/"),
            };
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Jwt-Token", JWTTokenManager.GetManager().GetToken());
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("tenantId", AppConst.TenanatID);
            return httpClient;
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteHttpTask(int taskType, string url, StringContent content = null)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClient();
            switch (taskType)
            {
                case HTTP_GET:
                    return await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                case HTTP_PUT:
                    return await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
                case HTTP_POST:
                    return await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
                case HTTP_DELETE:
                    return await httpClient.DeleteAsync(url);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<Response> HTTPTask(string url, int taskType, StringContent content = null, bool login = false)
        {
            Response httpResponse = new Response();
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await ExecuteHttpTask(taskType, url, content);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && !login)
                {
                    bool refreshTocken = await JWTTokenManager.GetManager().ValidateRefreshTocken(true);
                    if (refreshTocken == true)
                    {
                        response = await ExecuteHttpTask(taskType, url, content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        httpResponse = GenericErrorResponse();
                        return httpResponse;
                    }
                }

                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    httpResponse.status = "error";
                else
                    httpResponse.status = "data";
                httpResponse.data = ParseResponseData(httpResponse.status, responseString);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                httpResponse = GenericErrorResponse(e.Message);
            }
            return httpResponse;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look for wait all https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Unrelated: Your Singleton Implementation is not thread safe. Are you sure you do not have any problems with that?

Comment: @Fildor could you please elaborate on it.

Comment: I mean there could actually be more than one single instance of JWTTokenManager, theoretically. This could lead to problems. Especially if you are trying to sync your threads.

Comment: In all likelihood you are ignoring the implicit threading race bug.  Nothing you can do to ensure the token isn't going to expire *while* the threads are busy trying to use it.  So this isn't about blocking the threads, you have to restart them.

Comment: @Fildor that class is singleton right? so how can there be more than one instance??

Comment: @HansPassant even if they expire there is check for HTTP response which will again invoke a call to refresh token and retry the same, even at that time multiple threads can try the same, hence I want to block? Is that fine?

Comment: Followup to Hans' comment: No need to block, actually. If the token expires, the blocked requests should fail, anyway. So just cancel and retry. Now to the Singleton: Yes it is a Singleton and **in a Single-Threaded Environment**, it would be perfectly fine. I don't see why it needs to be lazy, but anyway - your choice. In a Multi-Threaded Environment, however, two Threads can enter the conditional block and create & retrieve 2 different instances of the "Singleton". This is very well described, just google something like "Threadsafe Lazy Singleton C#"

Comment: ... for example: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.8). Let's say you have three threads A, B (calling api calls in parallel) and C (performing token refresh).

```
private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(true);  // event is always set except when refreshing the token

Code on thread A,B

mre.WaitOne()  // it blocks whenever the event is reset
...


Code on thread C

mre.Reset() // this blocks all the waiting threads
perform the token refresh
mre.Set()  // this frees all the waiting threads
```

Comment: I really don't like how you say `mre.Reset()` "blocks all the waiting threads".  I would prefer to say, "When a thread waits on the event, it will block until the event becomes set."  It requires cooperation from the waiting thread.  The way you said it is technically false, because resetting an event ABSOLUTELY will not block a thread that is already waiting.  If the waiting thread saw that the event was set, then it's too late to reset it to cause the thread to block.  A thread specifically has to be not waiting to *eventually* cause it to block - an important aspect I hope to make clear.

Comment: > A thread specifically has to be not waiting to eventually cause it to block - an important aspect I hope to make clear
To be astonishing clear it's the wait call which makes a thread to block, if it is not waiting it won't block (except when you call Thread.Suspend on it)

Comment: Well an Event is a synchronization tool, so all threads must cooperate. Blocking threads is not a user program function (even though you can with Thread.Suspend) but an OPERATING SYSTEM function (and user programs mustn't do it). I think that probably the person who made the question wants to avoid to write the code to check if the token is expired after every function call and delegate its renewal to another thread, but you shouldn't do this way (you should resign to write the boilerplate code after each function call).

Answer (score 0):

You should make `JWTTokenManager` return a token instead of it needs a token.

If the token is valid, it will return a completed task with the valid token, if it's not, it will return a task that will complete when the token is retrieved. The same task can be awaited by multiple concurrent threads.

```
public class JWTTokenManager
{
    private Task<string> tokenTask;
    private readonly object sync = new object();

    public Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            if (tokenTask.IsCompleted && !IsTokenValid(tokenTask.Result))
            {
                tokenTask = GetNewTokenAsync();
            }

            return tokenTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Lock-free version:

```
public class JWTTokenManager
{
    private Task<string> tokenTask;
    private readonly object sync = new object();

    public Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var currentTokenTask = Volatile.Read(ref tokenTask);

        if (currentTokenTask .IsCompleted && !IsTokenValid(currentTokenTask .Result))
        {
            currentTokenTask = GetNewTokenAsync();
            Volatile.Write(ref tokenTask, currentTokenTask);
        }

        return currentTokenTask ;
    }
}
```

Comment: can a locked block contain async methods?

Comment: Let us say 5 threads need to get the token parallely, and if the existing token has expired then all five will try to fetch updated new token, hence I want all the others to wait until one/first request get the updated token and others continue. Is that fine?

Comment: can a block contain async methods or to be precise the error am getting is "cannot await in the body of a lock statemen"

Comment: @MidhunKumar, where's the async method?

Comment: @MidhunKumar, if concurrency really happens and is problem (for whatever reason) you can have a semaphore. But that's only a problem if concurrency is frequent and obtaining a token is costly.

Comment: The token expires every 24 hours. And there is a great chance parallel API calls will happen.

Comment: And why is that a problem? Anyhow, the task/token is evaluated inside a lock.

Comment: The error am getting is "cannot await in the body of a lock statemen"

Comment: Is there a reason you do not check `tokenTask` for `null`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado if i move the contents of the ValidateRefreshToken() inside a lock, then the async call to get the token throws that error, cannot wait in the body if a lock statement.

Comment: You don't! The code I posted has no async methods. It might call async methods, but it's not an async method.

Comment: @PauloMorgado fetching the token should be an async operation right?? we have to fetch it and then parse and update the token. So doesn't it need to be async ?? or are you suggesting to make it synchronous like HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url,content,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result; 
??

Comment: @all based upon all the comments I have added the updated classes. Please have a look.

Comment: @PauloMorgado please provide your suggestion as well regarding the last comment(synchronous refresh call with a .Result).

Comment: An asynchronous method is compiled into a state machine. The result will (usually) be a `Task`. A method that retrieves a `Task` and returns a `Task` doesn't necessarily need to be an asynchronous method to make the operation asynchronous, when it needs to be.

Comment: What you need is to implement the `GetNewTokenAsync()` method. That one can be an async method.

Comment: I have included the updated classes here does that help